# How to remove the background of an image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, graphics, binary, pixel

I would like to remove the hexagons in the below image

[image]

After loading the image file (I've used `vedo` library), I am not really sure how to proceed next.
I want to remove the hexagonal cells and then binarize the image (i.e convert the hexagonal cells in the background into white pixels) to extract the network.

```
from vedo import *
from skimage.io import imread


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = os.path.join("input.png")
    raw = load(f)
    show(raw)
```

[image file](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/Fig4a.png) ([image source](https://static-curis.ku.dk/portal/files/243061789/PhysRevLett.124.208101.pdf))

Suggestions on how to remove the hexagonal cells in the background will be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution would be extracting dark pixels by converting the image to the CMYK color space and extracting the K (Key - black) channel and thresholding it to achieve binary image.

Compute the K channel manually and set threshold using a fixed value(150 in this case). The code would look like the followings;
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs6FU.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# get grayscale image
def get_grayscale(image):
    # Convert to float and divide by 255:
    imgFloat = image.astype(np.float64) / 255.

    # Calculate channel K:
    kChannel = 1 - np.max(imgFloat, axis=2)

    # Convert back to uint 8:
    kChannel = (255 * kChannel).astype(np.uint8)
    # Threshold image:
    binaryThresh = 150
    _, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, binaryThresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    return cv2.bitwise_not(binaryImage)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = cv2.imread("input.png")
    gray = get_grayscale(image)
    cv2.imshow("image", gray)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows
```